# How to know if an atom is starting with a pattern?

Tags: string, prolog

For example, if I got the following predicates :

```
father('jim', 'Boby')
father('rob', 'bob')
```

and I would like to know who got father with is name starting with 'bo' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another ISO option is `sub_atom/5`:

`sub_atom(Atom, Before, Length, After, Sub_atom)`

```
?- sub_atom(bob, 0, _, _, bo).
   true.
```

Compared to `atom_concat/3`, this avoids the generation of the unneeded atom to represent the suffix.

Comment: At the user level, yes, using sub_atom/5 avoids an unnecessary atom. At the implementation level, and depending on the Prolog compiler, sub_atom/5 can be both slower and more costly (w.r.t intermediate atoms created) than atom_concat/3. If checking for an atom prefix is a frequent operation, it pays off to check the performance of both built-in predicates in the specific Prolog compiler being used.

Answer (score 4):

Simply use `atom_concat/3`, a ISO Prolog standard built-in predicate.